# Writing items from listbox to text file in C# with try-catch statment

Tags: c#, listbox, try-catch, streamwriter

My code it quite long but this is the part that I am stuck on. I have my try statement at the beginning before my for loops. But now I want to take my information that is in the ListBox and send it to a text file which I already have in my debug folder. I would like to just take my outputs from the list box and write them to the population.txt file.

//variable user input, store in userInput
            try
            {
                if (double.TryParse(startTextbox.Text, out start))
                {
                    if (double.TryParse(averageTextbox.Text, out average))
                    {
                        if (double.TryParse(daysTextbox.Text, out days))
                        {
                            //process
                            int count = 1;
                            while (count <= days)
                            {
                                //calculation
                                double output;
                                output = start * Math.Pow((1 + average / 100), count - 1);

```
                            //display the results in the listbox
                            populationListBox.Items.Add("The approximate population for " +
                                count + " day(s) is " + output.ToString("n2"));

                            //count the days
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        //used to text statement
                        //populationListBox.Items.Add("End of while loop");

                        count = 1;
                        do
                        {
                            //calculation
                            double output;
                            output = start * Math.Pow((1 + average / 100), count - 1);

                            //display the results in the listbox
                            populationListBox.Items.Add("The approximate population for " +
                                 count + " day(s) is " + output.ToString("n2"));

                            //count the days
                            count = count + 1;
                        } while (count <= days);
                        //used to text statement
                        //populationListBox.Items.Add("End of do-while loop");

                        //int count;
                        for (count = 1; count <= days; )
                        {
                            //calculation
                            double output;
                            output = start * Math.Pow((1 + average / 100), count - 1);

                            //display the results in the listbox
                            populationListBox.Items.Add("The approximate population for " +
                                 count + " day(s) is " + output.ToString("n2"));

                            //count the days
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        //used to text statement
                        //populationListBox.Items.Add("End of for loop");


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //error message for input
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for number of days to multiply.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //error message for input
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for average daily increase.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //error message for input
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for starting days");
            }


            StreamWriter outputFile;
            outputFile = File.CreateText("population.txt");

            outputFile.WriteLine("Approximate population: ");
            outputFile.WriteLine(populationListBox.Items);
            outputFile.ToString();
            outputFile.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        }
```

Comment: you need to show us the listbox contents before we can tell you how to write it to the file...

Comment: Did you try `foreach (string s in listBox1.Items){ outputFile.WriteLine(s); }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use library like [FileHelper](http://www.filehelpers.net/) to perform your job. It is open source and free. If you want to use just FileIO from .NET framework you can do that also

```
using (StreamWriter sr = File.CreateText("population.txt"))
{
      foreach (string s in listBox.Items)
      { 
          sr.WriteLine(s); 
      }
}
```